# Shift+End doesn't work on OS X like on a PC; Can this be fixed?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm usually on a PC, but recently, I've decided to give OS X a go (at work anyway). I don't have too many complaints. There is one, however, that is driving me up a wall.

<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> don't seem to work right. What's up with that? I'm very used to <kbd>Home</kbd> sending the cursor to the beginning of a line, <kbd>End</kbd> sending it to the end of a line, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> selecting everything to the left of the cursor while sending the cursor to the beginning of the line, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> selecting everything to the right of the cursor while sending the cursor to the end of the line.

I'm rocking Snow Leopard, and I have `KeyRemap4MacBook`. I try not to use it too much (after all, part of the reason I'm using OS X is to learn it), but this is one feature that I simply cannot live without. The only two things I have enabled on `KeyRemap4MacBook` are

1. Use PC Style Home/End, and
2. Use PC Style PageUp/PageDown.

<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> still don't work for most apps, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> don't work either.

Is there any way I can get those working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to learn the OS X way, move to the beginning of the line with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and move to the end of the line with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>. Combine with <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select text on the way.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that this doesn't work with Right Shift? Works fine with Left Shift though. Alright, I'll force myself to learn. Thanks!

Comment: @CodyS It works for me with any combination of left and right Command and Shift keys, so I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your key behaviour the way you like by install this [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html.en).

Go to the app's `Misc & uninstall` tab, click `private.xml` and replace its contents with this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>PC Home and End</name>
    <identifier>PC style</identifier>
  <autogen>
  __KeyToKey__
  KeyCode::HOME,
  KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L  
</autogen>
<autogen>
  __KeyToKey__
  KeyCode::END,
  KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L  
</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

then go change keys tab click `ReloadXml` on top right and tick the `PC Home and End` in the remapping block.

Finally, you have the PC style Home and End working.